# 2 column, left one adapts to content, the right one takes all remaning space

Tags: html, css

The columns should:

- be full height
- have vertical scrollbars if needed but no horizontal

This is what I got so far (along with a footer and a header)

http://jsfiddle.net/HZMCX/11/

The problem withmy code is that the right panel text starts at mid screen and not next to the left panel.

```
 [Ignore this, this is so stackoverflow allows me to post the link to jsFiddle ]
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Someone nailed it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463570/how-to-get-this-2-columns-layout-were-one-fits-to-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be applied much more simply than you currently have it:

Consider simply floating the side column and the primary content and setting fluid widths on both.
http://jsfiddle.net/MygUu/

Wrap the overall layout in a .container class, and set overflow to hidden.

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Additionally, it is best practice **not** to style using ID selectors. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi something must be wrong, the horizontal scrollbar is still visible and the text of the right panel doesnt fill the whole column (it still starts at mid the screen)

Comment: Add #left { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; } to solve the scrollbar issue.

Comment: Also, I have forked your fiddle once more with the floats. Constrain widths of #left and #right, float both left, and set a small margin on the left col to separate the two columns. http://jsfiddle.net/TjeYD/

Comment: but you are hard coding the widths, look at the title: "left one adapts to content, the right one takes all remaining space".

Comment: Without defining a constraint for the width somewhere (at the very least on #left), the content will naturally attempt to take up as much horizontal space as possible, thus pushing your primary content column below it.

Comment: The constraint is "left column adapts to content"