# How to get this 2 columns layout (were one fits to content)

Tags: html, css

Please note

- the vertical scrollbars should show up when needed
- left columns fits to width
- right column takes the rest of the space

[image: layout]

Comment: The `fits-to-width` left column may be hard to constrain depending on your content.  You may want to specify a max or min width.  Are you okay with using CSS table properties like `display: table-cell`?

Comment: Have you tried any code? if so, can you post it?

Comment: I am actually using your solution, simple and doing what stated! Thank you very much, I would never have realized that myself! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that uses CSS only.

The HTML looks like:

```
<div id="pageWrapper">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div class="table-wrap">
            <div class="cell col1">
                <div class="content">Column 1: Shrink-to-Fit Width</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell col2">
                <div class="content">Column 2: Variable Width</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footerWrapper">Footer</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
}
#pageWrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%; /*set to 100% or smaller or fixed width... */
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}
#contentWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background: beige;
}
#footerWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: gray;
}
.table-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table-wrap .cell {
    height: 100%;
}
.table-wrap .col1 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    max-width: 80%; /* This is critical or else Column 2 can disappear */
}
.table-wrap .col1 .content {
    height: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-wrap .col2 {

}
.table-wrap .col2 .content {
    height: inherit;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/kbAwf/

### How This Works

Use absolute positioning to place the header, main content area and footer within the view port area.

Within the content area (`#contentWrapper`), the `.table-wrap` container has two cells, one which is floated left (column 1).  This allows column 2 to fill the rest of the width.

To get the shrink-to-fit width for column 1, set `display: inline-block` to the inner `.content` container.

Finally, use `overflow-y: auto` for the scroll bars. (You can also use the scroll value.)

You need to set a maximum width to `.col1` so that `.col2` does not get pushed out of the view port.  I set it to 80% but you can adjust it.

Also, note that an inline-block will expand as much as possible to flow its content, which is why you need to constrain it.

You man want to set a minimum width on `#pageWrapper` to prevent the layout from shrinking to something that is less than useful.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/VNSnj/1/)**

**DEMO1 CSS**

```
 html, body {
    height:100%;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    height: 60px !important;
    opacity:.8;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    /*width:600px;  Sizing - any length */
    padding:60px 0 30px 0; /* Header height and footer height */
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; /* Center content */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.sidebar1, .sidebar2 {
    background: red;
    top:60px;
    bottom:30px;
    width: 70%;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.sidebar1 {

  left:0;
    width:30%;

}

.sidebar2 {
  right: 0;
}

#scrollable2 {
  background:green;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
    overflow:auto;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
```

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/uNMRT/2/)**

Comment: +1 I removed the width on the content and added text to get the look of the attached image http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/VNSnj/1/

Comment: Hi, the "width:30%;" in the .sidebar1 is hard coding the width, and it was supposed to fit to content. Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="mid">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.main {
    background-color: white;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
}
.main, .header, .left, .right, .mid, .footer {
    position: absolute;
}
.header {
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
.mid {
    top: 104px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 14px;
}
.left {
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.right {
    overflow-y:auto;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    border-left: 4px solid black;
}
.footer {
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRLge/5/)** (*as shown in your post*)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response! The left column though doesn't seem to fit to content, but thanks again!

Comment: Increasing width makes it to fit the content. did you try it atleast? It seems you are new to css as you have not used it anywhere.